# What is the benefit of ThreadGroup in java over creating separate threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

Many methods like `stop()`, `resume()`, `suspend()` etc are deprecated.

So is it useful to create threads using `ThreadGroup`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using `ThreadGroup` can be a useful diagnostic technique in big application servers with thousands of threads. If your threads are logically grouped together, then when you get a stack trace you can see which group the offending thread was part of (e.g. "Tomcat threads", "MDB threads", "thread pool X", etc), which can be a big help in tracking down and fixing the problem.

Comment: I've considered that in the past, and I don't think it gives you anything over just naming the threads appropriately.  If you can't modify the thread names however, or you have a tool that monitors thread activity aggregated by group, then that's a different matter.

Comment: Fair point, but the additional structure can be useful, for example aggregating CPU usage by thread group.

Comment: I use them in a very large enterprise application for this particular reason. I could have kept track of them myself but it would have forced me into writing quite a lot of code to manage the contents of my collection when thread finish, dies etc.

Answer (score 17):

Don't use `ThreadGroup` for new code. Use the [`Executor`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) stuff in [`java.util.concurrent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) instead.

Comment: Effective Java 2nd Ed. Item 73. Sadly, I think that the global community has been failed by the voting on the information in this question as it currently stands.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, which is "Why would I use it?" not "Should I use it?"

Comment: `ThreadGroup` and `Executor` are not mutually exclusive. You can use `Executors` with a `ThreadFactory` to create threads with a `ThreadGroup`.

Comment: It is true that they are not mutually exclusive: a new `Thread` created within a `ThreadFactory` can have a `ThreadGroup` injected into it, which, as the accepted answer states, can be used for grouping threads at scale, but, in general, there is still [ample (recent) evidence to support the notion that the `ThreadGroup` API is to be avoided](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/THI01-J.+Do+not+invoke+ThreadGroup+methods).

Answer (score 12):

Somewhat complimentary to the answer provided (6 years ago or so). But, while the Concurrency API provides a lot of constructs, the `ThreadGroup` might still be useful to use. It provides the following functionality:

1. Logical organisation of your threads (for diagnostic purposes).
2. You can `interrupt()` all the threads in the group. (Interrupting is perfectly fine, unlike `suspend()`, `resume()` and `stop()`).
3. You can set the maximum priority of the threads in the group. (not sure how widely useful is that, but there you have it).
4. Sets the `ThreadGroup` as a daemon. (So all new threads added to it will be daemon threads).
5. It allows you to override its `uncaughtExceptionHandler` so that if one of the threads in the group throws an Exception, you have a callback to handle it.
6. It provides you some extra tools such as getting the list of threads, how many active ones you have etc. Useful when having a group of worker threads, or some thread pool of some kind.

Comment: Too deep explanation, Thanks @jbx

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is - no, not really.  There's little if any benefit to using one.

To expand on that slightly, if you want to group worker threads together you're much better off using an ExecutorService.  If you want to quickly count how many threads in a conceptual group are alive, you still need to check each Thread individually (as ThreadGroup.activeCount() is an estimation, meaning it's not useful if the correctness of your code depends on its output).

I'd go so far as to say that the only thing you'd get from one these days, aside from the semantic compartmentalisation, is that Threads constructed as part of a group will pick up the daemon flag and a sensible name based on their group.  And using this as a shortcut for filling in a few primitives in a constructor call (which typically you'd only have to *write* once anyway, sicne you're probably starting the threads in a loop and/or method call).

So - I really don't see any compelling reason to use one at all.  I specifically tried to, a few months back, and failed.

EDIT - I *suppose* one potential use would be if you're running with a SecurityManager, and want to assert that only threads in the same group can interrupt each other.  Even that's pretty borderline, as the default implementation always returns true for a Thread in *any* non-system thread group.  And if you're implementing your own SecurityManager, you've got the possibility to have it make its decision on any other criteria (including the typical technique of storing Threads in collections as they get created).

Comment: How do you store a `Thread` in a collection as it is created. I can't see how you can tell when a thread is created.

Comment: The bit where you go `new Thread(...)`. :-)  Since a Thread can only be explicitly assigned to a group at construction time, it's reasonable to assume that the OP's code is explicitly creating them.  If he's not calling the constructor himself he can't change the thread group anyway.

Comment: "Threads constructed as part of a group will pick up the daemon flag". That's not quite right. The daemon thread is inherited from the parent Thread, not the ThreadGroup.

Answer (score 1):

Great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1649207/1697099) for @skaffman. I want to add one more advantage:

Thread groups helps manipulating all the threads which are defined in this at once.

Comment: Suspend is a deprecated option as you can also read in @jbx answer

Comment: there is no method to start a thread group. you have to individually start each thread.