# Why ThreadGroup is being criticised?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm aware of current practice of using Executors instead of ThreadGroup:

- generally preferred way to deal with Threads
- catching exceptions from threads, etc...

However, what are the inherent **flaws of ThreadGroup** as such (I've heard a vague criticism for that class)?

Thanks for answer.

PS. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649133/what-is-the-benefit-of-threadgroup-in-java-over-creating-separate-threads) does not seem to answer this question.

Comment: Argh I hate it when people say "don't use ThreadGroup".  It's like saying "don't use Threads".  A thread has a ThreadGroup, there's no getting around that, so unless you want to have a program with no threads, **you are using ThreadGroups**.  I agree we need a question to address *when, how and why* not to use them.

Comment: +1 for the reasons that Mark Peters states, and because this question is a good vehicle to do so.

Comment: @matt b: To pick more opinions in absence of a definite answer.

Comment: @MarkPeters This is the suggestion from Joshua:
"Thread groups are best viewed as an unsuccessful experiment, and you should simply ignore their existence. If you design a class that deals with logical groups of threads, you should probably use thread pool executors (Item 68)." So would you please give us some examples on when, how and why to use ThreadGroups?

Comment: @sheidaei: Well this was from a few years ago, but my comment was **not** saying we should be using thread groups (for anything).  I was trying to say that the common (at the time) rule "don't use ThreadGroup" in itself wasn't useful or enlightening, because it doesn't explain why, and because all Threads actually use ThreadGroup one way or another.  Therefore this question was a good one to go into better detail (i.e. "don't use ThreadGroup to accomplish X, instead use Y").  That's all I was saying.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is explained in [Effective Java 2nd Ed.](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Effective-Java-Second-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683), Item 73.

> Thread groups were originally envisioned as a mechanism
>   for isolating applets for security purposes. They never really fulfilled this
>   promise, and their security importance has waned to the extent that they aren’t
>   even mentioned in the standard work on the Java security model [Gong03].
>
> [...] In an ironic twist, the `ThreadGroup` API is weak from a thread safety
>   standpoint. To get a list of the active threads in a thread group, you must invoke
>   the `enumerate` method, which takes as a parameter an array large enough to hold
>   all the active threads. The `activeCount` method returns the number of active
>   threads in a thread group, but there is no guarantee that this count will still be
>   accurate once an array has been allocated and passed to the `enumerate` method. If
>   the thread count has increased and the array is too small, the `enumerate` method
>   silently ignores any threads for which there is no room in the array.
>
> The API that lists the subgroups of a thread group is similarly flawed. While
>   these problems could have been fixed with the addition of new methods, they
>   haven’t, because there is no real need: **thread groups are obsolete**.
>
> Prior to release 1.5, there was one small piece of functionality that was available
>   only with the `ThreadGroup` API: the `ThreadGroup.uncaughtException`
>   method was the only way to gain control when a thread threw an uncaught exception.
>   This functionality is useful, for example, to direct stack traces to an application-
>   specific log. As of release 1.5, however, the same functionality is available
>   with `Thread`’s `setUncaughtExceptionHandler` method.
>
> To summarize, thread groups don’t provide much in the way of useful functionality,
>   and much of the functionality they do provide is flawed. Thread groups
>   are best viewed as an unsuccessful experiment, and you should simply ignore their
>   existence. If you design a class that deals with logical groups of threads, you
>   should probably use thread pool executors (Item 68).

Comment: Thanks for quote. So do I correctly understand that we in our practice should completely avoid ThreadGroup inspite of the fact that it still remains inside Thread methods: start() and init(ThreadGroup g, Runnable target, String name, long stackSize), the latter is called from Thread() constructor and always builds ThreadGroup?

Comment: Thanks for marking CW and for the ref.  Finally bought the book but haven't got that far yet.  The `uncaughtException` functionality was actually the last bit I was curious about.

Comment: @Max General-purpose library code should still be aware of which `ThreadGroup` it is creating theads in. So, for some purposes, you still have to deal with it.

Comment: @Max, usually yes (with some exceptions, as @Tom noted). Note that since Executor is preferable to dealing with Threads directly, you should hardly ever even see a ThreadGroup anymore.

Comment: They are useful for debugging. If you are creating threads, then putting them in their own named `ThreadGroup` is still a good idea, rather than having a mess of unrelated functionality in the `main` group.