# Loop through a ThreadGroup - please help me debugging

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop

I try hard to find the problem in this Java code, but I can't find it - can you help me?

I hope the code I provide is enough, but I will post more if necessary.

Further I apologize, I didn't make a minimal example.

```
game.getGroupPlayers().list();
MoverThread[] playerThread = game.getPlayers();
System.out.println(playerThread.length);
for (int i = 0; i < playerThread.length; i++) {
    try {
        System.out.println(i + " -> " +playerThread[i].toString());
        returnString += playerThread[i].toString() + "\n";
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem at i = " + i);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    game.getGroupPlayers().list();
}
```

sometimes gives me the following output:

> java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=Players,maxpri=10]
>       Player-0: 113
>       Player-1: 277
>       Player-2: 0
>   3
>   0 -> Player-0: 113
>   1 -> Player-1: 277
>   Problem at i = 2
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at Referee.goalFound(Referee.java:70)
>       at DebugTestReferee.goalFound(DebugTestReferee.java:42)
>       at Player.checkGoal(Player.java:61)
>       at Player.run(Player.java:94)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
>   java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=Players,maxpri=10]
>       Player-0: 113
>       Player-1: 277
>       Player-2: 0

[edit]
here's the source of getPlayers()

```
/*
 * post returns the games players as an array
 */
public MoverThread[] getPlayers() {
synchronized(movers) {
    MoverThread[] playerList = new MoverThread[players.activeCount()];
    players.enumerate(playerList);
    return playerList;
}
}
```

[edit]
here's how players is generated

```
private ThreadGroup movers;
private ThreadGroup players;
private ThreadGroup ghosts;

private Observer observer;

/*
 * constructor
 */
 public Game(Maze maze, Referee referee) {
this.maze = maze;
this.referee = referee;
threadList = new ArrayList<MoverThread>();
movers = new ThreadGroup("Movers");
players = new ThreadGroup(movers, "Players");
ghosts = new ThreadGroup(movers, "Ghosts");
observer = null;
}
```

[edit]

Here's how I call the method that generates the problem:

```
/*
 * post checks if the players thread was interrupted - if not if hostfield pretends to be a goal the game gets stopped and referee is called to perform "goal-found-actions"
 */
private void checkGoal() {
if (!getThread().isInterrupted()) {
    synchronized(getGame().getMovers()) {
        if (!getThread().isInterrupted()) {
            if (getHostField().isGoal()) {
                Field goal = getHostField();
                getGame().getReferee().goalFound(this, goal);
                getGame().setGameOver();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and here's the whole goalFound()

```
/*
 * post action to be performed if a player finds a goal
 * print some information
*/
public void goalFound(Player player, Field at) {
//FIXME get the Bug!!!
String returnString = "Game over - player " + player.getName() + " found a goal on (" + at.getPos()[0] + ", "  + at.getPos()[1] + ")!\n";
game.getGroupPlayers().list();
MoverThread[] playerThread = game.getPlayers();
System.out.println(playerThread.length);
for (int i = 0; i < playerThread.length; i++) {
    try {
        System.out.println(i + " -> " +playerThread[i].toString());
        returnString += playerThread[i].toString() + "\n";
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem at i = " + i);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
game.getGroupPlayers().list();
returnString += game.mazeString();
System.out.println(returnString);
}
```

Comment: The exception is not being thrown in code called from this loop... it looks like the exception is happening in one of the other threads and is getting output at the same time as the loop you show.  Look in class `Referee` line 70, where the NPE is being thrown.

Comment: Referee.java line 70 is  
System.out.println(i + " -> " +playerThread[i].toString());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution - or maybe more a workaround...

Beside using ThreadGroups I store my threads in an ArrayList aswell (maybe a Vector would be even better, but I'm fine with the ArrayList).

I don't know why, but when I try to call all Threads in the ThreadGroup it often happens that some Threads are left out. However, with the ArrayList it works fine.

Would be interesting why ThreadGroups don't work as supposed and what we need them for in this case.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a nice way of enumerating the `Thread`s of a `ThreadGroup`. It's a well known terrible design.

Between calling `ThreadGroup.activeCount` and `ThreadGroup.enumerate(Thread[])`, threads may have started or died. The best you can do is add a fudge factor the `activeCount` when allocating the array. If the returned value matches the array length, then you may have missed some and should repeat with a larger array size (probably a factor larger, rather than just adding a constant). When successful, you will need to trim your array appropriately (or treat it as such).

Comment: I'm open to any solution!
In the specific case however no thread should have started or died, because of two reasons: 1. threads are generated only in the beginning of the program, threads are only killed at the end of the program 2. (and more important) I call this method when movers are synchronized (I will edit my source to show that). However, if this could solve my problem - please tell me how!

Comment: I don't think the semantics of the use of locking a `ThreadGroup` is defined. In the Sun/Oracle implementation of `Thread` the behaviour is a little unexpected. Generqally it's a bad idea to extend `Thread`, and using `ThreadGroup` isn't typically a great idea. Using a subtype of `Thread` for the `Thread[]` array passed to `ThreadGroup.enumerate` is a bit dangerous, and it appears undefined what happens if an inappropriate `Thread` subclass is present (it throws an `ArrayStoreException` from the look of the Sun/Oracle source).

Comment: Bloch argues against use of `ThreadGroup` in *Effective Java*. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3265640/545127

Answer (score 1):

`game.getPlayers();` is returning `MoverThread[]` with length 3, but the third one is `null`.

Comment: yea, that's what the error says. however that can't be... see edit

Comment: So then `players.enumerate(playerList);` is what is not setting the third one.

Comment: first I want to say I appreciate your help very much.

players is a Threadgroup (will add it shortly to my post) and so players.enumerate(list) should therefore be a standard java method...

Comment: `activeCount()` returns an estimate.

Comment: yea. this COULD be a problem. However the output shows, that right before and right after the exception the method game.getGroupPlayers().list(); returns 3 players, but the exception says player 3 is null

Comment: Include `isAlive()` in your `playerThread.toString()` implementation. If that is false for one, then it will be counted in the activeCount, shown in list(), but not included in the enumerate() result.