# How does enumerate() method of ThreadGroup works?

Tags: java, enumerate, threadgroup

The `int enumerate(Thread[] list)` function updates the specified `list[]` (of the calling function) with the info about active threads .How is it possible?? The `list[]` is passed as an argument to the enumerate function without it's reference and the function returns only an int value.So how does the changes made to `list[]` are reflected back in the calling function `list[]` ???

Comment: [Don't use ThreadGroup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265640/why-threadgroup-is-being-criticised)

Comment: You know that Java is pass by value but uses object references? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java everything is passed **by value**, but you're confusing a **reference to the object instance** with the **object instance itself**.

In your case,  the reference of array `list[]` is passed by value, this means that no matter if you modify the reference (for example doing `list[] = new list[5]`, when the method ends, this new reference will be lost because it was passed by value (that is, a copy of the original value was sent to the method).

But you can indeed modify the object instance pointed by this reference (for example `list[5] = new Thread()`) and when the method returns, this object will stay modified (if the object is mutable, that is).