# What are Thread Groups in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am wondering why there is so little documentation about Thread Groups on the internet ? 
Are they still used or they are some stale concepts ? 
Can some one explain:

- What they are.
- What they are used for.
- If they are stilled used, where ?
- Give some real application examples (web servers like, maybe).

Comment: The short answer is: [a mistake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265640/why-threadgroup-is-being-criticised).

Comment: If you feel the cited answer answers your question, I can close your question as duplicate.

Comment: @biziclop The question is asks for more specific issues and the question claims to understand it well, this question however is about explaining the basics which I myself don't understand. Moreover don't understand why none talks about it :D

Comment: @biziclop I use ThreadGroups for different purposes, so I don't consider them to be obsolete.  They might be brain dead simple, but sometimes simple is all you need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are used as a Group of Threads.  In a simple application you only need one, but in a more complex application server it makes sense to have one for each application.

> why there is so little documentation about Thread Groups on the internet ?

I guess some assume it's a pretty simple idea.  Not sure what is missing about it.

> Are they still used or they are some stale concept ?

I would image most developers never think about Thread Groups. But I think they are useful in certain situations.  We have a library where we have a custom ThreadGroup for resetting thread affinity.

> Can some one explain that are they what they are used for, if still used, and give an example.

Mostly in applications servers, each server has it's own collection of threads and can be managed collectively.  If you want to monitor or shutdown an application your need to know which threads the application started.

If you start off a thread in a ThreadGroup, every Thread it creates will also be in that thread group.  Without this feature, you would have a hard time assigning threads to applications.

> From @biziclop: How do you reliably enumerate threads in a group?

You can get the size of activeThreads and enumerate as the ThreadGroup locks on `this` (for better or worse)

```
synchronized(threadGroup) {
    Thread[] threads = threadGroup.activeCount();
    threadGroup.enumerate(threads);
    // use threads before the lock is released or it could be wrong.
}
```

Comment: That is fine but can you point some articles, other than java 101, or examples how to use them and what they are useful for ?

Comment: @Adelin I would read the Javadoc for Thread Group and possibly the source for ThreadGroup and Thread.  What is your doubt specifically?

Comment: @Adelin Like I said, most Java developers never think about it, ever, so it's not a Java 101 class.

Comment: A thread group represents a set of threads. In addition, a thread group can also include other thread groups. The thread groups form a tree in which every thread group except the initial thread group has a parent.
A thread is allowed to access information about its own thread group, but not to access information about its thread group's parent thread group or any other thread groups. I don't think it is enough do you ?

Comment: @Adelin actually you can navigate around the tree, so you can get from one thread group to another.  What do you think is missing?

Comment: @biziclop ThreadGroup locks on `this` which means you can do it externally, I have added to my answer.

Comment: I guess a lot of developers, who work with thread and should consider thread groups, are working with certain/several thread pools instead. So they don't work with this class directly.

Comment: @Tom I agree.  Most developers should be using 1) parallelStream(), 2) ExecutorService, 3) possibly ForkJoinPool, 4) plain Threads, and highly unlikely, last) Thread Groups.

Comment: Sorry for the possibly stupid question from a non-Java developer, but is this what a process is in other environments such as native Windows?

Comment: @FelixDombek The JVM is a process and on Linux each Thread works like a Process (and has it's own Process id)  A Thread Group is a cross between a List and a Tree of Threads at best, at worst it is tricky to find a good use for it.  The OS has no idea this exists.