# What is the difference between Thread[main,5,main] and Thread[Thread-77416,5,main]

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have created a worker thread,

```
Thread thread= new Thread(runnable);
thread.start();
```

I print this in worker thread;

```
    Log.d("SessionThread", Thread.currentThread().toString());
```

I get following output;

> Thread[Thread-77416,5,main]

and when i try `Thread.currentThread()` on main thread from my activity. It prints following.

> Thread[main,5,main]

Now i am unable to understand why the 3rd argument is `main` in the worker thread log message.

I need to understand whats these arguments means, I googled this but unable to find out any help about the parameters of `Thread.currentThread()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Thread#toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#toString()) returns "a string representation of this thread, including the thread's name, priority, and thread group".

So the first part is the thread's name. The name can be passed to the `Thread(String)` constructor upon creation, or configured through `setName()`. If no name is assigned, a default of the form `"Thread-" + n` is used. The initial thread is apparently called `"main"`, though I'm not sure this is standardised.

The second part is the priority, configured through `setPriority()`.

The third part is the thread group. This is set through the `Thread(ThreadGroup, ...)` constructors. If not specified at thread creation time, the value of [`SecurityManager.getThreadGroup()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#getThreadGroup()) is used, which by default is the current thread's thread group. This means that, by default, any thread created by the `main` thread will also be in the same thread group as the `main` thread.

Comment: Thanks for such detail answer :) 1 more question will this make any impact on `main thread`, if worker thread group is `main`. As android starts lacking, if more operations are performed in `main thread`. I created worker thread to take off some load from main thread.

Comment: There is no performance impact from both threads being in the same group. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649133/what-is-the-benefit-of-threadgroup-in-java-over-creating-separate-threads) for a discussion of the benefits of thread groups.

Answer (score 2):

Thread[Thread-77416,5,main] = **"Thread[" + getName() + "," + getPriority() + "," +
                           group.getName() + "]";**

**Thread-77416** name of the thread, if not set system will assign one, programmer can set this either by using setName() or while creating the new instance of thread example

```
 Thread t = new Thread(this, "This is Thread Name");
```

**5 is the priority** means NORM_PRIORITY Priority, this is the default priority. Thread has following Range of Priority

```
    /**
     * The minimum priority that a thread can have.
     */
    public final static int MIN_PRIORITY = 1;

   /**
     * The default priority that is assigned to a thread.
     */
    public final static int NORM_PRIORITY = 5;

    /**
     * The maximum priority that a thread can have.
     */
    public final static int MAX_PRIORITY = 10;
```

**main mean Thread group name** to which this thread belongs

Example Code

```
public class ThreadExample implements Runnable {

   ThreadExample() {
      // main thread
      Thread currThread = Thread.currentThread();

      // thread created
      Thread t = new Thread(this, "This is Thread Name");

      System.out.println("Main thread = " + currThread);
      System.out.println("Thread created = " + t);

      // this will call run() function
      t.start();
   }

   public void run() {
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      new ThreadExample();
   }
}
```

**OutPut**

Main thread = Thread[main,5,main]

Thread created = Thread[This is Thread Name,5,main]

Answer (score 2):

Third argument is group name.If you will not provide Thread group ,the Thread group will take from parent thread which created your child thread.In your case it is main method.

Thread toString() method.

```
public String toString() {
       ThreadGroup group = getThreadGroup();
       if (group != null) {
           return "Thread[" + getName() + "," + getPriority() + "," +
                          group.getName() + "]";
       } else {
           return "Thread[" + getName() + "," + getPriority() + "," +
                            "" + "]";
        }
    }
```