# What is active thread group in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadgroup

There is method java.lang.ThreadGroup.activeGroupCount() returns an estimate of the number of active groups in a thread group. In response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360030/what-defines-an-active-thread), the active thread is defined. But what does active thread group mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, the terminology "active thread group" appears in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#activeGroupCount()) for `ThreadGroup::activeGroupCount`.

An active thread group is a `ThreadGroup` containing at least one active thread.

An active thread is one for which `Thread::isAlive` returns `true`.  In other words, it has been started and has not yet terminated.

---

Note that thread groups are are only really suitable for debugging; see [What is the benefit of ThreadGroup in java over creating separate threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649133/what-is-the-benefit-of-threadgroup-in-java-over-creating-separate-threads).  For example, the `enumerate` method has this [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#enumerate(java.lang.Thread[],%20boolean)) caveat:

> *"Due to the inherent race condition in this method, it is recommended
>   that the method only be used for debugging and monitoring purposes."*

This also applies to the "count" methods.

Answer (score 2):

In Java there is a *group abstraction* around a group of threads, so it is easier to manage a group of threads. See e.g. [Java: Thread Group](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/threads/group.html)

> Every Java thread is a member of a thread group. Thread groups provide a mechanism for collecting multiple threads into a single object and manipulating those threads all at once, rather than individually.
>
> For example, you can start or suspend all the threads within a group with a single method call. Java thread groups are implemented by the ThreadGroup(in the API reference documentation) class in the java.lang package.

Comment: Thanks. But what does it mean for a thread group to be active?

Comment: Those numbers is just for monitoring, the important thing is the state of the threads. See e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#activeCount()

Comment: Not exactly dead.  A thread that has not been started yet also counts as "not active".

Comment: *"What if a thread group does not contain any thread?"* - Then it does not contain any active threads and is therefore not an active thread group.